# Store Invoke-Sqlcmd Query as String

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I have a value that I want to find and pull out of a database. I have everything I need in order to run this script except how to store the result in a variable and then write those results to a txt file

```
$CNumber = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query ("Select Cust From SY.CompanyCode") -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Database $Database

Add-Content $Mobile $CNumber
```

When it writes the results in the text file it looks like this:

```
System.Data.DataRow
```

When I just run the Invoke-Sqlcmd and don't try to store it in a variable I can see the correct value. So I'm assuming once this query runs, I need to convert the results somehow?

Please and thank you.

Comment: _Please and thank you._ ... Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the result of the query is a `System.Data.DataRow`, PowerShell first needs to convert the `DataRow` to a `String` before it can be used with `Add-Content` and the easiest way to convert any object into a `String` is to use the `ToString()` method.

You can check this yourself by calling

```
$CNumber.ToString()
```

and it should show up in the console as:

```
System.Data.DataRow # OR System.Object[] if there are multiple DataRows
```

As you're only selecting one column you can simply access the property on the `DataRow` but keeping in mind that the query may return multiple `DataRow`s we should loop through them, something like this:

```
foreach($row in $CNumber.Cust)
{
    # row will be equal to each cust from the query
    # add row to your file here
}
```

Comment: And see that's the weird part, I tested this exact method before I posted my question, and for some reason I still end up with System.Data.Datarow.

Comment: Found why this wasn't working, per .NET specifications .tostring will output the object type. In order to convert it I need to run the following:

Add-Content $Mobile $CNumber.itemarray

Thank you so much for your time. Cheers!